# Generating Keypair using bouncy castle in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I have Java code for generating keypair as follows:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(1024);
KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey priv = key.getPrivate();
PublicKey pub = key.getPublic();
```

Now I want to do same in j2me using BC. I have downloaded latest bouncy castle library from [Bouncy castle latest release](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Here i want to do same in j2me. Below is my code for generating public and private key for j2me:

```
 RSAKeyPairGenerator generator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
     generator.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(new BigInteger("10001", 16),//publicExponent
            SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"),
            1024,
            80
            ));
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();

    AsymmetricKeyParameter myprivatekey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) keyPair.getPrivate();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter mypublickey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) keyPair.getPublic();
```

Now i want to get byte array of public key and private key but there is no such method to get encoded bytes directly from AsymmetricKeyParameter class. By googling I have found below solution to get bytes from the AsymmetricKeyParameter .

```
   PrivateKeyInfo   pkInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.createPrivateKeyInfo(myprivatekey);
   byte[] privateKey = pkInfo.getEncoded();
```

This code should be work but unfortunately my netbeans showing java.lang.Error: ClassFormatError: when i run this code.

Please help me how to resolve this error or let me know any other alternative by which i can get bytes from AsymmetricCipherKeyPair as i want to send this key to my server using socket connection. FOr your information i m using Netbeans 6.9.1 and j2ME SDK 3.0.5 to build my j2me application.

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Here is my full midlet code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.RSAKeyPairGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyGenerationParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PrivateKeyInfoFactory;

/**
 * @author nirav.bhandari
 */
public class RSAClientMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    public void startApp() {

        Form f = new Form("Test");
        Command cmd = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
        f.addCommand(cmd);

        f.setCommandListener(this);
        Display d = Display.getDisplay(this);
        d.setCurrent(f);

        RSAKeyPairGenerator generator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
        generator.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(new BigInteger("10001", 16),//publicExponent
                SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"),
                1024,
                80));
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();

        AsymmetricKeyParameter myprivatekey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) keyPair.getPrivate();
        AsymmetricKeyParameter mypublickey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) keyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("Done");
        PrivateKeyInfo pkInfo;

        try {

           pkInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.createPrivateKeyInfo(myprivatekey);
           // i get classformat error here. un
           byte[] privateKey = pkInfo.getEncoded();
  SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.createSubjectPublicKeyInfo(mypublickey);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        destroyApp(true);
    }

    private void show(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

here is my stack trace of errror

```
    TRACE: <at java.lang.Error: ClassFormatError:  78>, startApp threw an Exception
java.lang.Error: ClassFormatError:  78
        at RSAClientMidlet.startApp(), bci=123
        at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletTunnelImpl.callStartApp(), bci=1
        at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletPeer.startApp(), bci=7
        at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.startSuite(), bci=273
        at com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=52
        at com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=8
        at com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.runMIDletSuite(), bci=161
        at com.sun.midp.main.AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26
java.lang.Error: ClassFormatError:  78
        at RSAClientMidlet.startApp(), bci=123
        at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletTunnelImpl.callStartApp(), bci=1
        at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletPeer.startApp(), bci=7
        at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.startSuite(), bci=273
        at com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=52
        at com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=8
        at com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.runMIDletSuite(), bci=161
        at com.sun.midp.main.AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26
javacall_lifecycle_state_changed() lifecycle: event is JAVACALL_LIFECYCLE_MIDLET_SHUTDOWN status is JAVACALL_OK
```

Comment: Please post your full strack trace.

Comment: @dunkan: i have added strack trace in my question..please find it and do any needful if possible.. thanks in advance.

Comment: did yu get my app's stack trace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassFormatError: 56 while using hessian in j2me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688257/classformaterror-56-while-using-hessian-in-j2me)